# Where do Nintendo ROMs (GBC/GBA) come from?

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance, game-boy

I was wondering, who created the ROMs for GBA and GBC emulators? Are they "converted" from the actual games or are they created from scratch trying to recreate the game? I think the first one, otherwise it would be insane.. And if it's the first one, who could do that? Some engineers inside Nintendo or just some random dude?

P.S.: I'm not interested in a guide or how-to, just a general information to understand the situation.

Comment: The data is pulled from the cartriges. Who could do it? People with the correct equipment and software to allow it. Can we help you do it? No, because doing so is almost certainly illegal. We have a [post on the meta site](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/795/what-exactly-does-the-law-state-about-emulation-and-roms) that goes into a little more detail - but not the "how".

Comment: A guide might be the only thing we *can* help you with. Figuring out where existing roms come from is a complete lost cause; there's no data, usually, to help you backtrack it.

Comment: @JonK - The act of pulling a ROM from a cartridge is **not** illegal - it is covered by the 'backup/archival copy' clauses of the DMCA. Making that copy available for download by other people or otherwise distributing the game **is** illegal.

Answer (score 5):

The information will be kept general and unlinked here for obvious reasons, but there are pieces of equipment that can accept a GBA cartridge, and then connect to a PC.  That would allow read access to a cartridge, and depending on the cart you can write to some as well.  You might imagine it a bit like an SD card reader, except cartridges only contain one large blob of data, not any filesystem or such. ROMs are usually just dumps of the cartridge contents to disk using such a device, but it is also possible to write and compile your own, and with a "blank" cart to write to you can use one to test and develop your own games for the GBA as well.

Comment: Since the question toes the line (but hasn't yet been closed), please advise if the answer does as well, will be removed if it does.

Comment: Depending on the ROM, there may also be some "recreating from scratch" involved; back in the day it was not uncommon for cartridges to include [additional processing chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_NES_enhancement_chips) in addition to the game data itself. This added expense but let developers do things that the console on its own wasn't powerful enough to handle.

For games using these chips, just dumping the ROM contents isn't enough; these addon chips have to be identified and reverse-engineered, a process that can take years.

Answer (score -2):

I have seen videos on Youtube of people who make custom ports of games for cartridge based media. In this case it was called an eprom chip inside the bare cartridges that the person would remove and read/write to this chip itself. I would presume a similar chip may be found inside Gameboy carts and making a dump of such chip may be one way that a ROM could be created.

This could also in theory explain why flashcarts are able to function presuming they are primarily redirecting and redistributing data which would otherwise be located at this storage media chip to an externally mounted sd card.

Comment: You know, if you want to remove your answrs, there's an actual _delete_ button for that.

Comment: im using the app and dont see such an option

Comment: [Seems that the Android-app doesn't have that implemented yet.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app) Never the less, this is a wrong way to delete an answer. We'd perfer if you'd wait untill you can access the site from a browser and delete your answers through the site proper.

Comment: @Firobug - if you could supply one of these YouTube videos you mention it would go a long way into improving the answer: as it currently stands it's very speculative with not a lot of facts/references backing it up.

Comment: I never do use a browser just the app on my phone....also thats another admin thing...not only should app allow delete but explaine why I should have 3 down votes ticking 2rep each against me with no stated reason why my answer was struck down....I simply suggested an alternative solution I know to work.

Comment: Downvotes are by _other users_. Nobody's required to explain them (altough this is encouraged if there's a chanse the answer may be improved). Downvoting for frivolous reasons is discouraged by downvotes _costings 1 rep each_.